# Trouble with C++ Regex POSIX character class

Tags: c++, regex, clang++

I'm trying to create a regex that is capable of analysing something like this:

> 002561-1415179671591i.jpg

The second part is a unix timestamp (before the i), and I need to extract that. I came up with the following syntax, but std::regex keeps throwing a regex_error before I even check for a match and I'm not too sure what's wrong.

Here's what I've got so far:`([:d:])*-[[:d:]]*([:alpha:])\.jpg`

The C++ code line that throws the error is the constructor to regex

```
std::regex reg(regex_expr);
```

where `regex_expr` is a string that has been read in from a file.

Really appreciate any help you can give.

Edit: I wrote a try catch section, and it seems I'm getting the following error code

`std::regex_constants::error_brack`

Edit 2: Ok... seems I'm still getting the error even with a cut-down test:

`([:alpha:])*`

Edit 3:

Seems I can't get any expression to work. Here's a bit more info. I'm using clang++ 3.5.0 on Kubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You want to create the `std::regex` object from your pattern string (the "([:d:])*-[[:d:]]*([:alpha:])\.jpg"), then use `regex_match` (or whatever) to see if that pattern matches some string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tests, for whatever reason, I couldn't get this to work. As I had boost anyway, I tried out the boost::regex and it worked straight away, so I presume that something to do with either clang, or the version of the standard on this pc just wasn't working.

So simply put, tried boost and it worked straight away. Not much of an answer, but I guess that's how things go sometimes.

Comment: I think the problem is your compiler version, gcc doesn't support regex before the 4.9 version.

Comment: That may very well by why. Unfortunately, I'm stuck as this code is not just for me but others that use the same OS version, thus stuck at version 4.8. Guess I'll have to stick to boost...

Answer (score 3):

Not sure that `[:d:]` can stand for `[:digit:]`. [EDIT] (It seems it's possible)

When you use a POSIX character class, it must be enclosed in a character class like that:

```
[[:digit:]]
```

*(This syntax allows to compose other classes `[[:digit:]ab]`)*

so:

```
std::string regex_expr = "([[:digit:]]*)-([[:digit:]]*)([[:alpha:]])\\.jpg";
```

or if you use the basic mode:

```
std::string regex_expr = "\\([[:digit:]]*\\)-\\([[:digit:]]*\\)\\([[:alpha:]]\\)\\.jpg";
```

Comment: When I tried this (I directly copy/pasted your code) I still get the std::regex_constants::error_brack that I got with my version...

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use the perl-compatible syntax instead of character classes:

```
\d+-(\d+)[a-z]*\.jpg
```